# Maximum Size of HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

So Basically I am generating random 10000 ip address and I wanted to store all those ip address that are found in HashSet but according to my calculation around 6000 ip address were found but in HashSet only 700 ip address are getting stored? Is there any limitations in HashSet in terms of storing String. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
   Set<String> ipFine = new HashSet<String>();
        long runs = 10000;
            while(runs > 0) {

            String ipAddress = generateIPAddress();

            resp = SomeClass.getLocationByIp(ipAddress);

            if(resp.getLocation() != null) {

                 ipFine.add(ipAddress);
                        }

               runs--;

         }
```

Comment: Maybe 9300 times resp.getLocation() is null or generateIPAddress() returns the same String?

Comment: Another possibility, however remote, is that given the relatively structured form of IP addresses, you might get a lot of hash conflicts. I.e. several distinct IP addresses have the same hashCode (which is used to determine whether or not that thing is already in your set). This is unlikely, though.

Comment: This is definitely homework! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745459/store-distinct-ip-address-in-hashset added tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as you're concerned, there is no limit (the limit is the max size of an array, which is 2**31).

However, `Sets` only store *unique* values, so my guess is that you only generated 700 unique addresses.

Modify your code as follows:

```
if(resp.getLocation() != null) {
    if (ipFine.add(ipAddress)) { // add() returns true if the value is unique
        runs--; // only decrement runs if it's a new value
    }
}
```

This modification will mean you'll keep looping until you get 10000 *unique* values.

Comment: ,So what should I call inside the if loop. Can you add that part also inside the if loop. means how can I try again and add it to HashSet.

Comment: @RaihanJamal I've changed the code so you can copy-paste it in

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you had 6000 *distinct* IP addresses? My guess is that you had 6000 IP addresses, but most of them were duplicates...

You're definitely *not* running into a maximum size issue.

(Note that the code you've given isn't valid anyway - you've declared `ipFine` twice.)

Comment: That was by mistake. I declared twice. I have removed that.

Comment: @RaihanJamal: Any chance you could fix the indentation at the same time? It's all over the place at the moment...