# Store distinct ip address in HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum Size of HashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745214/maximum-size-of-hashset)

How can I add distinct ip address in  HashSet

```
Set<String> ips = new HashSet<String>();

String ip = generateIPAddress();


   if (!ips.add(ip)) { 

// What should I do here?

    }


private String generateIPAddress() {

        Random r = new Random();

        //Now the IP is b1.b2.b3.b4
        String s = r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256) + "." + r.nextInt(256);

        return s;

    }
```

Comment: homework??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745214/maximum-size-of-hashset

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

`add()` returns `true` if it's a new value, so:

```
while (!ips.add(ip)) { 
    ip = generateIPAddress(); // try again
}
```

This keeps looping until you add a new unique value.

Theoretically it could loop forever, but if your random generator is reasonable it will eventually find a new unique value.